# SQL: How to check a string for multiple values from another table

Tags: sql, oracle

I am trying to parse through a string to see if values from another table appear in it in any position.

```
select ROUTE,
case when ROUTE like '%' || b.AIRPORTCODE || '%' then 1 
else 0 end as CLASS_B,
case when ROUTE like '%' || c.AIRPORTCODE || '%' then 1 
else 0 end as CLASS_C
from FLIGHT_MESSAGE, 
(select * from CLASS_B_C_AIRPORTS where CLASS_B_C = 'B') b,
(select * from CLASS_B_C_AIRPORTS where CLASS_B_C = 'C') c
```

The CLASS_B_C_AIRPORTS table will have an airport code (KDCA) and whether or not it is 'B' or 'C'.

In my example below, ROUTE field will contain a string of text like:

```
KDCA..FLUKY.DCA246.PAUKI..MOL.FLCON6.KRIC/0127
```

For this string, I'd like to return the following, because KDCA is a Class B airport and KRIC is a Class C airport:

```
| ROUTE                                          | CLASS_B | CLASS_C |
----------------------------------------------------------------------
| KDCA..FLUKY.DCA246.PAUKI..MOL.FLCON6.KRIC/0127 | 1       | 1       |
```

This query currently returns 0's for Class B and Class C against this string.

Comment: So, what does "1" represent in your results? 1 = true, 0 = false? (there is at least one CLASS_B airport code in your string and at least one CLASS_C airport)? Or are they **counts** of CLASS_B and CLASS_C airport codes in the input string?

Comment: Also, how do you plan to avoid the "mother is in che**mother**apy" problem? What if your input string has the substring MVFA, and there is a CLASS_B airport with code VFA, or MVF?

Answer (score 1):

I think this is what you want:

```
SELECT ROUTE,
       MAX(CASE WHEN CLASS_B_C = 'B' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as CLASS_B,
       MAX(CASE WHEN CLASS_B_C = 'C' THEN 1 ELSE 0 END) as CLASS_C
FROM FLIGHT_MESSAGE fm JOIN 
     CLASS_B_C_AIRPORTS a
     ON fm.ROUTE LIKE '%' || a.AIRPORTCODE || '%'
GROUP BY ROUTE;
```

Comment: That is returning a 0 for Class B and 1 for Class C.  It should be 1 and 1.

Comment: @QuangNguyen . . . I suspect something is wrong with your data.  I think this query should do what you intend (although you might want a `left join`).

Comment: This will almost surely require some refinement (working with the OP) to avoid the "mother is in chemotherapy" problem. (You are searching for the code "mother" and you find it, inadvertently, in the input string "che**mother**apy".)